# Query on Multiple datatable at once

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two Datatables

```
Datatable dt1  and Datatable dt2
```

Which contains some records. And i have where statement like

```
dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName AND dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName AND dt1.columnName   = dt2.columnName
```

and want to fire this query like

```
Dattatable.Select("dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName AND dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName AND dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName")
```

and return either first Datatable or Second Datatable.
The Select Statements is Dynamic which contains sometime "AND,OR" combination.
Means

```
 Datatable.Select("(dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName AND dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName )    OR (dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName AND dt1.columnName = dt2.columnName)" )
```

And want to do this without for loop(Quickest way) as Datatable may contains Limited Columns but millions of Records.

How to do this?

Comment: where u have used for loop? plz paste the code

Comment: Dont want to use Loop. @F.R.I.E.N.D.S.

Comment: but i want to see ur for loop code

Comment: are u there bhosale san?

Comment: You might use Computed DataColumns with values from dt2 when you add a relation to those tables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx